# std::reverse with reverse iterators, why isn't it a no-op?

Tags: c++

Take this minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string s{"abcde"};
    std::reverse(s.rbegin(), s.rend());
    std::cout << s;
}
```

Since we are reversing a range of reverse iterators, I expect it to be a no-op. But it prints `edcba`. What don't I understand about reverse iterators or `std::reverse`?

Comment: ["Reverses the order of the elements in the range [first, last)
Behaves as if applying std::iter_swap to every pair of iterators first+i, (last-i) - 1 for each non-negative i < (last-first)/2"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse)

Comment: Do you expect negating a negative number to be a no-op? Do you also expect doing a U-turn on a return trip to be a no-op? If not, why not?

Comment: One might expect doung U-turn twice is a no-op. Or, to be more precise, doing U-turn while sitting backwards;)

Answer (score 1):

Algorithms operate on ranges. `std::reverse` did its job and [`s.rbegin()`, `s.rend()`) is now `"abcde"`. `std::cout << s;` will print it from the other end, so `"edcba"`.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the swapping operations are symmetric, so it doesn't matter whether you go from `s.begin()` to `s.end()` or from `s.rbegin()` to `s.rend()`.

To visualize this, first consider what happens when going forwards (from `s.begin()` to `s.end()`), using your example of <kbd>abcde</kbd>:

- <kbd>a</kbd> is swapped with <kbd>e</kbd>. The string is now <kbd>ebcda</kbd>.
- <kbd>b</kbd> is swapped with <kbd>d</kbd>. The string is now <kbd>edcba</kbd>.

The reversal is now finished (<kbd>c</kbd> is in the middle and doesn't need to move).

Now consider what happens when going backwards (from `s.rbegin()` to `s.rend()`):

- <kbd>e</kbd> is swapped with <kbd>a</kbd>. The string is now <kbd>ebcda</kbd>.
- <kbd>d</kbd> is swapped with <kbd>b</kbd>. The string is now <kbd>edcba</kbd>.

The end result is the same, since the swaps are symmetric.

According to the C++ standard:

> **25.3.10 Reverse** [alg.reverse]
>
> ```
> template<class BidirectionalIterator>
> void reverse(BidirectionalIterator first, BidirectionalIterator last);
> ```
>
> *Effects:* For each non-negative integer `i < (last - first) / 2`, applies `iter_swap` to all pairs of iterators `first + i`, `(last - i) - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

it is ok,
finally it uses swap(*_Left, *_Right); so it changes the original string s
see the source:

```
template<class _BidIt> inline
    void reverse(_BidIt _First, _BidIt _Last)
    {   // reverse elements in [_First, _Last)
    _DEBUG_RANGE(_First, _Last);
    _Reverse(_Unchecked(_First), _Unchecked(_Last), _Iter_cat(_First));
    }
template<class _BidIt> inline
    void _Reverse(_BidIt _First, _BidIt _Last, bidirectional_iterator_tag)
    {   // reverse elements in [_First, _Last), bidirectional iterators
    for (; _First != _Last && _First != --_Last; ++_First)
        _STD iter_swap(_First, _Last);
    }
template<class _FwdIt1,
    class _FwdIt2> inline
    void iter_swap(_FwdIt1 _Left, _FwdIt2 _Right)
    {   // swap *_Left and *_Right
    swap(*_Left, *_Right);
    }
```